# I am having trouble changing the url.py within Django

Tags: python, django

Hello I am needing assistance. I am currently doing within `url.py` for Django:

`urlpatterns` = [
path('cookies/', admin.site.urls),
]

This is being done from urls.py in atom and when I look at the terminal it is not  able to GET the new url. When I have 127.0.0.1/cookies/   I am still directed to a not found page. Anyone please  help I am currently using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Could you share the full urls.py and does the page not found display what URL patterns it tried?

Comment: Does http://127.0.0.1:8000/cookies/ work?

Comment: hello @GregCowell thank you for the speedy response. Unfortunately I wish it did work but I get a page not found message with the following text:                

Using the URLconf defined in wordcount.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/

The current path, cookies/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: @Lemon.py Hello and thank you. When I go to url.py I see this: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('cookies/', admin.site.urls),                 
]

I am a complete beginner, I do apologize if this is not adequate information.

Comment: Okay and no problem, are you using separate urls.py files for multiple apps in your project?

Comment: Admin urls are default by Django. It looks like you just changed to cookies. Before you changed, did original path admin/ work?

Comment: @ha-neul Thank you and yes! In fact if I still input 172.0.0.1:8000/admin/ It will still successfully reach the admin login page despite the url.py being changed to cookies. I am having a hard time figuring out how to actually have the cookies take over as practice.

Comment: @Lemon.py So far I am just using one url.py I don't think that I am running or have added apps to the project yet. believe so far for and have only started one project and ran the one project thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are changing an `urls.py` from your app not from your main project's `urls.py`.

You generated this file byyourself, right?

If you want to change your admin path, go to your main projects' `urls.py`.It is in the same folder as `settings.py`.

If you cannot find it, just search for `admin.site.urls` in your text editor.

Comment: Thank you! it worked! I went to the actual url.py from the actual project and not through the atom editor I was using and it is now working I really appreciate it! @ha-neul